# Tomcat error 404 with Spring MVC app in Intellij Idea

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, tomcat

My Spring MVC app doesn't run. Error 404: the requested resource [/] is not available. I use Spring 6, Intellij Idea Ultimate and Tomcat 10.1. In my Java code i have @GetMapping('/') which returns home.html page and i don't understand why it doesn't work.

**Controller:**

```
package com.webJava.library.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    public MainController(){
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**LibraryApplication:**

```
package com.webJava.library;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LibraryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LibraryApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.webJava</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>web library</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I don't understand this error. What is it?
Here is catalina log:

```
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.185 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.1.16
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.188 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 10 2023 16:17:33 UTC
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.188 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 10.1.16.0
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.188 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.188 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Версия ОС:             10.0
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.188 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Архитектура:           amd64
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.189 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Users\Konstantin\.jdks\openjdk-21.0.1
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.189 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Версия JVM:            21.0.1+12-29
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.189 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Производитель JVM:     Oracle Corporation
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.189 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Konstantin\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.3\tomcat\776a8840-5723-41bc-b37c-1c95077d3d14
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.189 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Tomcat v10.1
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.192 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Konstantin\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.3\tomcat\776a8840-5723-41bc-b37c-1c95077d3d14\conf\logging.properties
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.192 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.192 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.192 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.193 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.193 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Users\Konstantin\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.3\tomcat\776a8840-5723-41bc-b37c-1c95077d3d14\jmxremote.password
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.193 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Users\Konstantin\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.3\tomcat\776a8840-5723-41bc-b37c-1c95077d3d14\jmxremote.access
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.193 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.193 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.193 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.193 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.193 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.194 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.194 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.195 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.195 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Konstantin\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.3\tomcat\776a8840-5723-41bc-b37c-1c95077d3d14
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.195 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Tomcat v10.1
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.196 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Tomcat v10.1\temp
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.207 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Users\Konstantin\.jdks\openjdk-21.0.1\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Users\Konstantin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Konstantin\.dotnet\tools;C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin;;C:\Users\Konstantin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;.]
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.456 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Инициализация ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8083"]
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.485 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [617] milliseconds
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.566 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.566 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.16]
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.583 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8083"]
19-Dec-2023 19:30:58.640 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [153] milliseconds
19-Dec-2023 19:31:06.418 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

Comment: Do you see this problem if the application was started from the command line via Maven outside of the IDE? E.g., via spring-boot maven plugin